# scroll content under image without interruption

Tags: javascript

I have a div loading content from an other html page with a banner over it. I would like to know if it's technically possible to create a text who moves, without going under the banner so without interruption.

I'm using jScrollPane:

```
<li id="menu1"><div class="link-bg"><a href="#sur-toute-la-ligne">SUR TOUTE LA LIGNE</b></a></div></li>
```

What did you suggest me?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index to put it on top?

```
#menu1 {
  position:relative;
  z-index:9999;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately, I can't put the banner on the top, it would be so easy ;)

I put a screenshot on the link below to illustrate my problem:
http://www.freelance-webdesign.com/screenshot/floating-text.jpg